# Acer Iconia A500: sd card contents not showing up in windows explorer

Tags: android-sdcard

I have written a simple app that writes a string to a text file for the acer a500 tablet. The output file "something.txt" is visible under ddms of eclipse and also via the tablet file explorer. But when I use the windows explorer, even though the directory in which the file resides is visible, the file is not showing up.

The file is being stored in the internal storage space(~12GB) of the tablet.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Android version:3.2

Min sdk:12

Comment: I think Windows explorer only shows /mnt/sdcard.  By the way, there is an upgrade to Android 3.2

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that I have to refresh (press F5) sometimes in Windows Explorer.